# Enable google Cloud Resource Manager API by python client API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

if the api is not enabled, usually error will be like

`HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json returned "Cloud Resource Manager API has not been used in project 684373208471 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developers console API activation', 'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxxx'}]}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'SERVICE_DISABLED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'consumer': 'projects/xxxxxxxxxxx', 'service': 'cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com'}}]">`

Does google provide API for enabling some api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud provides an API to enable APIs. This is called **Service Usage API**.

[Service Usage REST API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest)

[Service Usage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/libraries)

Example code that I wrote to display a list of enabled APIs in Python:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

project = 'projects/myproject'

service = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.services().list(parent=project)

response = ''

try:
    response = request.execute()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

# FIX - This code does not process the nextPageToken
# next = response.get('nextPageToken')

services = response.get('services')

for index in range(len(services)):
    item = services[index]

    name = item['config']['name']
    state = item['state']

    print("%-50s %s" % (name, state))
```

The output of this code looks similar to this (truncated for this answer):

```
abusiveexperiencereport.googleapis.com             DISABLED
acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com            DISABLED
accessapproval.googleapis.com                      DISABLED
accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com                DISABLED
actions.googleapis.com                             DISABLED
adexchangebuyer-json.googleapis.com                DISABLED
adexchangebuyer.googleapis.com                     DISABLED
adexchangeseller.googleapis.com                    DISABLED
adexperiencereport.googleapis.com                  DISABLED
admin.googleapis.com                               ENABLED
adsense.googleapis.com                             DISABLED
```

[API Documentation for my example code](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/serviceusage_v1beta1.html)

Comment: you just show code to view which api is enabled,    but how to enable them by api

Comment: @LukAron - Your question was **Does google provide API for enabling some api?**. I answered that and provided additional information to help you use the API. You did not specify a language. I thought Python would be an easy to read language to help you write your own software. This link shows the **enable** method to call: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/serviceusage_v1beta1.services.html#enable

Comment: will highly appreciate it if python examples could be provided, I have read the doc too,      but I find it difficult to use, also doesnt find relevant code in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples

Comment: @LukAron - Your question has been answered. Please do not use comments to ask for more things. You can create another question.